# Pdf signing with bouncycastle using pdfbox 2.x.x

Tags: bouncycastle, pdfbox

I tried to find example of signing pdf with pdfbox version 2.x.x in bouncycastle , what i see is only with pdfbox version 1.8.9

https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/sign/CreateSignature.java

This works for pdfbox 1.8.9 but not for 2.x.x versions the apis have changed. Could not find documentation specific to the same usecase but in 2.x.x versions of pdfbox.

Could anyone please help here.

Comment: While it is nice that you look at one of my github repos for example code, you should always first look at the official examples at apache.org, e.g. `CreateSignature` [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples are in the source code download or online here:
https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/

Below is the current CreateSignature example. However you'll need the other files from the directory above. The file structure may change from time to time when new features are added; so the code below is more a kind of snapshot. The best is to retrieve the current code from the link above or from a release.

```
public class CreateSignature extends CreateSignatureBase
{

    /**
     * Initialize the signature creator with a keystore and certficate password.
     *
     * @param keystore the pkcs12 keystore containing the signing certificate
     * @param pin the password for recovering the key
     * @throws KeyStoreException if the keystore has not been initialized (loaded)
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException if the algorithm for recovering the key cannot be found
     * @throws UnrecoverableKeyException if the given password is wrong
     * @throws CertificateException if the certificate is not valid as signing time
     * @throws IOException if no certificate could be found
     */
    public CreateSignature(KeyStore keystore, char[] pin)
            throws KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException
    {
        super(keystore, pin);
    }

    /**
     * Signs the given PDF file. Alters the original file on disk.
     * @param file the PDF file to sign
     * @throws IOException if the file could not be read or written
     */
    public void signDetached(File file) throws IOException
    {
        signDetached(file, file, null);
    }

    /**
     * Signs the given PDF file.
     * @param inFile input PDF file
     * @param outFile output PDF file
     * @throws IOException if the input file could not be read
     */
    public void signDetached(File inFile, File outFile) throws IOException
    {
        signDetached(inFile, outFile, null);
    }

    /**
     * Signs the given PDF file.
     * @param inFile input PDF file
     * @param outFile output PDF file
     * @param tsaClient optional TSA client
     * @throws IOException if the input file could not be read
     */
    public void signDetached(File inFile, File outFile, TSAClient tsaClient) throws IOException
    {
        if (inFile == null || !inFile.exists())
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Document for signing does not exist");
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

        // sign
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(inFile);
        signDetached(doc, fos, tsaClient);
        doc.close();
    }

    public void signDetached(PDDocument document, OutputStream output, TSAClient tsaClient)
            throws IOException
    {
        setTsaClient(tsaClient);

        int accessPermissions = SigUtils.getMDPPermission(document);
        if (accessPermissions == 1)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No changes to the document are permitted due to DocMDP transform parameters dictionary");
        }     

        // create signature dictionary
        PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
        signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
        signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        signature.setName("Example User");
        signature.setLocation("Los Angeles, CA");
        signature.setReason("Testing");
        // TODO extract the above details from the signing certificate? Reason as a parameter?

        // the signing date, needed for valid signature
        signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());

        // Optional: certify 
        if (accessPermissions == 0)
        {
            SigUtils.setMDPPermission(document, signature, 2);
        }        

        if (isExternalSigning())
        {
            System.out.println("Sign externally...");
            document.addSignature(signature);
            ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning =
                    document.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(output);
            // invoke external signature service
            byte[] cmsSignature = sign(externalSigning.getContent());
            // set signature bytes received from the service
            externalSigning.setSignature(cmsSignature);
        }
        else
        {
            // register signature dictionary and sign interface
            document.addSignature(signature, this);

            // write incremental (only for signing purpose)
            document.saveIncremental(output);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
    {
        if (args.length < 3)
        {
            usage();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String tsaUrl = null;
        boolean externalSig = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            if (args[i].equals("-tsa"))
            {
                i++;
                if (i >= args.length)
                {
                    usage();
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                tsaUrl = args[i];
            }
            if (args[i].equals("-e"))
            {
                externalSig = true;
            }
        }

        // load the keystore
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        char[] password = args[1].toCharArray(); // TODO use Java 6 java.io.Console.readPassword
        keystore.load(new FileInputStream(args[0]), password);
        // TODO alias command line argument

        // TSA client
        TSAClient tsaClient = null;
        if (tsaUrl != null)
        {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            tsaClient = new TSAClient(new URL(tsaUrl), null, null, digest);
        }

        // sign PDF
        CreateSignature signing = new CreateSignature(keystore, password);
        signing.setExternalSigning(externalSig);

        File inFile = new File(args[2]);
        String name = inFile.getName();
        String substring = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf('.'));

        File outFile = new File(inFile.getParent(), substring + "_signed.pdf");
        signing.signDetached(inFile, outFile, tsaClient);
    }

    private static void usage()
    {
        System.err.println("usage: java " + CreateSignature.class.getName() + " " +
                           "<pkcs12_keystore> <password> <pdf_to_sign>\n" + "" +
                           "options:\n" +
                           "  -tsa <url>    sign timestamp using the given TSA server\n" +
                           "  -e            sign using external signature creation scenario");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is also now available in github repository.
https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateSignature.java